# protege v 3.4.8 does not recognize transitive property

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, protege

I have created object property hasSibling where A hasSibling B, B hasSibling C.I have made this property as transitive and symmetric,
but in inferred instances it is not showing A hasSibling C.

This is showing correctly in protege v4.3 but I am using protege v3.4.8 
in my project where i have to use  transitive and symmetric object properties.
I have tried Sparql query also but it is showing result for symmetric not for transitive.

```
    PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX uni:<http://www.owl-ontologies.com/aa.owl#>
select * where { 
  ?x uni:hasSibling  ?y .
}
```

this is giving result as:
[Where in inferred tab nothing came](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LR0i.png)
Kindly suggest how to overcome this problem.

Comment: Some questions: which reasoner do you use? And are you sure that inferred facts will be shown? I never used Protege 3.x and we already have Protege 5.x. What is the reason for using this old version? BY the way, I'm pretty sure that the SPARQL processor does not consider reasoning. Even in Protege the default SPARQL tab doesn't do this.

Comment: Unless you provide your data and tell us whether you have a reasoner enabled, this isn't really a reproducible problem.  Also note that Protege 4.x is rather old;  Protege 5 has been available for quite some time.

Answer (score 0):

Given the query:

```
  PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX uni:<http://www.owl-ontologies.com/aa.owl#>
select * where { 
  ?x uni:hasSibling  ?y .
}
```

You need to have a reasoning that understands the semantics of the uni:hasSibling relation which is more than likely described in the ontology identified by the URI: http://www.owl-ontologies.com/aa.owl# .

If you were using Virtuoso, this would require the following:

1. Derive and Inference Rule from
   http://www.owl-ontologies.com/aa.owl#
2. Execute your query with a pragma for invoking the Inference Rule
   created in the first step plus another pragma for loading your data
   (collection of subject and objects connected by uni:hasSibling
   relationship type)

I provide a similar example in my [post](https://medium.com/virtuoso-blog/using-british-royal-family-data-snippets-to-demonstrate-sparql-query-language-based-reasoning-56626a152419#.m9438vb6h) that demonstrates Reasoning & Inference using British Royal Family relationship types. Also note a recent [follow-on post](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/reasoning-inference-using-british-royal-family-part-idehen) that shows how you can create your own Custom Inference Rules.